# Cannot cancel a KeyEvent

Tags: android, bluetooth, onkeydown

I have a Bluetooth barcode scanner that acts as a hardware keyboard. I implemented these methods in my `Activity` (just testing):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d("debug", "up: "+KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode));

    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d("debug", "down: "+KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode));

    return true;
}
```

Yet, whatever I return (be it `true` or `false`), the keys are always also handled by the default handler, resulting in unwanted behavior.

**Update** it seems to be missing the `KEYCODE_ENTER`, which is handled by a default handler. I tried explicitly setting `setDefaultKeyMode(DEFAULT_KEYS_DISABLE)`, but it had no effect.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: To "eat" the event, you should use return true. So when you return true, what in your applications makes you know that the key event is not "eaten" ?

Comment: @Gaëtan it focuses on the ActionBar and clicks "Enter", resulting in the closing of the Activity.

Comment: @Gaëtan not only that, it also misses the last `KEYCODE_ENTER` that the scanner sends.

Answer (score 0):

There are some buttons on the `Activity`'s view that were focused. The focused `Button` would get my `KEYCODE_ENTER` and handle it, leaving nothing for my Activity.